# Two forms on one page (exactly the same forms) one submits and one doesn't

Tags: forms, validation

I have two forms on one html page. One is in a modal box and one is in a sidebar.

The one in the modal box submits and works fine.

The one in the sidebar does not sumbit and causes the one in the modal box to produce "enter your email address" error. Its like the one in the sidebar is trying to submit the one in the modal box.

(modal box is pure css no js)

Here is my form code:

```
    <div class="agent-contact-form">
                                  <h4><?php _e('Enquire About: ','framework'); ?><span class="accent-color"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span></h4>
<form method="post" id="agentcontactform" name="agentcontactform" class="agent-contact-form" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/mail/agent_contact.php">
<input type="text"  id="name" name="Your Name" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Your Name','framework'); ?>">                                        
<input type="email"  id="email" name="Email Address" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Email Address','framework'); ?>">
<input type="phone"  id="phone" name="Phone Number" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Phone Number','framework'); ?>">
                                      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Your message','framework'); ?>" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
                                      <input type="hidden" name="image_path" id="image_path" value="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>">
                                      <input id="agent_email" name="agent_email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id ); ?>">
                                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" name="subject" id="subject">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Submit','framework'); ?></button>
                                  </form> </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Here is my action code:

```
    <?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
if(!$_POST) exit;

function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
 if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter your email address.</div>';
exit();
} elseif(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter a message.</div>';
exit();
}
else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter a valid email address.</div>';
exit();
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
$address = "me@domain.com";
$e_subject = (isset($subject))?$subject:'Contact Form';
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name from the domain website, their phone number is $phone and their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact them via their email, $email";
$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );
$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
if(wp_mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {
// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3><br>";
echo "<p>Thank you $name, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
echo "</div>";
} else {
echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Here is the validation:

```
    REAL.AgentContactForm = function(){
    $('.agent-contact-form').each(function(){
        var formInstance = $(this);
        formInstance.submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="' + $('#image_path').val() + 'images/assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.post(action, {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            name: $('#name').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
                            agent_email: $('#agent_email').val(),
                            subject: $('#subject').val(),
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('.agent-contact-form img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('.agent-contact-form').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
}
```

I have tried to make a new action and rename the form, rename everything really so the 2 forms are different but it still did the same thing.